# Design a subclass of a generic container , which should also be type specific

Tags: java, containers, generic-list

So there is a class called Product. Which has products like ComputerParts and Fruit. I have made a container called genericOrder which accepts type product. I'v added an object of ComputerPart to it. Now i need to Have a subclass of genericOrder called computerOrder which takes the subclasses of ComputerParts which are Ram, CPU etc.

How do i link the container to genericOrder ? 
i have attached the code below . Forgive me i am very new to programming

```
import java.util.*;
public abstract class GenericOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List < Product > genericOrder = Arrays.asList(new ComputerPart(12), new ComputerPart(76f),
        new Service(26f), new Cheese(26f), new Fruit(26f), new Peripheral(26f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain - link contain to genericorder? What container and what do you mean by link

Comment: i meant to say how do i make computerOrder a subclass of another container such as genericOrder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics. Something on these lines...

```
public class GenericOrder<T extends Product> {
     public void placeOrder(List<T> products);
}
```

Then:

```
public class ComputerOrder extends GenericOrder<ComputerProduct> {
     public void placeOrder(List<ComputerProduct> products)
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the <T extends Product> implementation and what does the placeOrder accomplish ?

Correct me if i am wrong . GenericOrder<ComputerProduct> is upcasting rite ? Can i use the same adding asList method in your second part ?

Comment: Never mind i have practiced what you taught. I get it.
Bless you and have a nice day